# INNER JOIN mysql limits

Tags: php, mysql

I use `INNER JOIN` to join 3 tables based on same value. My query looks like this:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM cases v INNER JOIN calculations c
            ON v.case_id = c.case_id
            INNER JOIN positions p
            ON v.case_id = p.case_id
            WHERE v.vin = :vin
            ORDER BY c.name DESC
            LIMIT 5";
```

But here is a problem:

1. I need to disply always just last calculation
2. Select from positions should be multiple results for same case_id

How ever I try to limit something it always limit all results not just one part of it.

PHP code is simple, just echo values:

```
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['vin'];
                    echo "<br>".$row['case_id'];                                
                    echo "<br>".$row['claimnumber'];                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['platenumber'];                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['accident_date'];                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['mileage'];                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['model_options'];                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['laborcosts'];                    
                    echo "<br>".$row['paintmaterial'];                                      
                    echo "<br>".$row['text']; 
                    echo "<br>-----------------------";
```

My actual result looks like:

```
ABCDEFG
49
09.4852DAZ
3B6 8303
0000-00-00 00:00:00
0
JASDKSD
5810
12151,82
NÁRAZNÍK P V-Z
-----------------------
ABCDEFG
49
09.4852DAZ
3B6 8303
0000-00-00 00:00:00
0
JASDKSD
5810
12151,82
PREDNÉ SKLO VYMENIŤ
```

But it should looks like:

```
ABCDEFG
49
09.4852DAZ
3B6 8303
0000-00-00 00:00:00
0
JASDKSD
5810
12151,82
PREDNÉ SKLO VYMENIŤ
NÁRAZNÍK P V-Z
-----------------------
```

Sorry if I add to many code, just want to make sure, that its understandable. 
If here someone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify the columns you want and use `DISTINCT` or you can use a `GROUP BY vin`.

Comment: You are getting multiple values because you didn't identified columns that will lead to **ambiguous column_name**

Comment: I need data from column text in table positions to be displayed all and all other data just once. 

Also there should be multiple lines of result in table calculations and there should be chose just one line ( the last one)

If iam right DISTINCT WILL help with column text but will not help with display just one LAST result from calculations

How can I specify it?

Comment: For a cleaner code use `foreach ($row as $val) echo "<br>$val";`